# Using a reserved characters in a query string in hash fragment

Tags: javascript, url, web, query-string

I am trying to save the state of a client sided web application in the hash fragment part of the URL as shown below

```
example.com/#m=1&i1=240000&i2=4.5&i3=30y&i4=4/1998&c1&c2&c3&c4
```

I would prefer not to encode the hash fragment to try and keep the URL length as short as possible.

I have done some testing and everything seems to work just fine cross browser.

However, I have read that one of the characters I would like to use (backslash) is reserved for URL query params.

My question is are there are any consequences of not encoding the reserved characters?

Comment: The URL is not a datastore, don't use it as such. Use sessionstorage or localstorage, that's what they were meant for.

Comment: I am trying to make the state of the app bookmarkable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slash is not reserved by [RFC 3968](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5):

> The characters slash ("/") and question mark ("?") are allowed to
> represent data within the fragment identifier.  Beware that some
> older, erroneous implementations may not handle this data correctly
> when it is used as the base URI for relative references ([Section
> 5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.1)).